# The meaning of "at most" in the definition of space complexity of a Turing machine

Tags: complexity-theory

From Ullman and Hopcroft's *Introduction to automata theory, languages, and computation*  1ed 1979

> Consider the off-line Turing machine M of Fig. 12.1. M has a read-only
>   input tape with endmarkers and k semi-infinite storage tapes. If for
>   every input word of length n, M scans **at most** S(n) cells on any
>   storage tape, then M is said to be an S(n) space-bounded Turing
>   machine, or of space complexity S(n). The language recognized by M is
>   also said to be of space complexity S(n).
>
> ...
>
> The family of languages of space complexity S(n) is denoted by
>   DSPACE(S(n));

1. Does "at most" mean taking the maximum or an upper bound?
2. By the definition, assume there is another function S'(n) so that
   S'(n)>S(n).

   - If an offline Turing machine M has space complexity S(n),  does M also have space complexity S'(n)?
   - If a language is in DSPACE(S(n)), is it also in DSPACE(S'(n))?
3. Is it incorrect to say that **the** complexity of an offline Turing
   machine is S(n)? Instead should we say that an offline Turing
   machine has complexity S(n) or S'(n)?

Thanks.

Comment: It's like big-O bounds. Certainly if a TM has space complexity $n^2$ then it will also have space complexity $n!$, so as with big-O, there isn't one space complexity, but (infinitely) many. Obviously it would be best to find the minimal space complexity, but often we can't (at least without a lot more work).

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Does "at most" mean taking the maximum or an upper bound?

It means "at most". $x$ is at most $y$ iff $x\leq y$.

> 2. By the definition, assume there is another function $S'(n)$ so that $S'(n)>S(n)$.
>   If an offline Turing machine $M$ has space complexity $S(n)$, does $M$ also have space complexity $S'(n)$?

Yes. Let $\ell(x)$ be the number of tape cells used for input $x$.  We have $\ell(x)\leq S(|x|)\leq S'(|x|)$, where the first inequality is by the fact that the machine uses space at most $S(|x|)$ and the second by the assumption about $S'$. Therefore, $M$ has space complexity $S'(n)$.

> If a language is in DSPACE(S(n)), is it also in DSPACE(S'(n))?

Yes. If you can decide it using at most some amount of space, you can also decide it using some bigger amount of space.

> 3. Is it incorrect to say that **the** complexity of an offline Turing machine is $S(n)$? Instead should we say that an offline Turing machine has complexity $S(n)$ or $S'(n)$?

It's a little loose to say that **the** complexity is $S(n)$, since "the" suggests a unique thing, whereas, as you've observed, a language actually has infinitely many space complexities. But people say it all the time, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of including the phrase 'at most' in the definition is to account for the fact that Turing machines often rescan one or more cells as they run, but a cell scanned more than once only counts as one cell for purposes of counting total used space.  So the answer to (1) above is that S(n) is an upper bound on the total number of scanned cells (which can only be achieved in practice by machines which never rescan any cells).  That 'looseness' is helpful if one cannot figure out precisely how cells are re-used -- simply assume they never are, and analyze accordingly.

And I would say that the phrase 'THE complexity is S(n)' should be reserved for when we can show that S(n) is the -smallest- function (in the big-O sense) that successfully measures the machine's complexity [i.e if S'(n) is a 'smaller' function than S(n), then the machine must take more than S'(n) space on one or inputs, but never more than S(n) space].

Comment: No. A machine that visits cells more than once can perfectly well visit exactly $S(n)$ cells. For example, it could move the head right $S(n)$, then move it all the way back to the left, then halt. Further, there is no "smallest function (in the big-O sense)". For example, $n^2=O(n^2-1)=O(n^2-2)=\dots$.